# PostgreSQL - (Somewhat) complex SQL query - need to span multiple tables and do annotations

Tags: sql, postgresql

Given the following schema:

```
CREATE TABLE "organization_building" (
       "id" serial NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
       "name" varchar(255) NOT NULL);
CREATE TABLE "organization_calendar" (
       "id" serial NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
       "name" varchar(255) NOT NULL);
CREATE TABLE "organization_event" (
       "id" serial NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
       "start" timestamp with time zone NOT NULL,
       "end" timestamp with time zone NOT NULL, "calendar_id" integer NOT NULL);
CREATE TABLE "organization_floor" (
       "id" serial NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
       "name" varchar(255) NOT NULL,
       "building_id" integer NOT NULL, "calendar_id" integer NULL);
ALTER TABLE "organization_event" ADD CONSTRAINT "organization_event_calendar_id_433ca4c752778f76_fk_organization_calendar_id" FOREIGN KEY ("calendar_id") REFERENCES "organization_calendar" ("id") DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED;
CREATE INDEX "organization_event_9c13da14" ON "organization_event" ("calendar_id");
ALTER TABLE "organization_floor" ADD CONSTRAINT "organization_floor_building_id_6152d8c8b88bbaea_fk_organization_building_id" FOREIGN KEY ("building_id") REFERENCES "organization_building" ("id") DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED;
ALTER TABLE "organization_floor" ADD CONSTRAINT "organization_floor_calendar_id_66357b835616383c_fk_organization_calendar_id" FOREIGN KEY ("calendar_id") REFERENCES "organization_calendar" ("id") DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED;
CREATE INDEX "organization_floor_4c63c6ae" ON "organization_floor" ("building_id");
CREATE INDEX "organization_floor_df2e10dc" ON "organization_floor" ("calendar_id");
```

Given a datetime range (beginning and end) how can I get results in the following format:

```
| Building_Id | Building_Name   | Floors_Total | Floors_Available |
|-------------+-----------------+--------------+------------------|
|           1 | First Building  |           10 |                5 |
|           2 | Second Building |           20 |               20 |
```

An "available" floor is described here:

1. It **MUST** have a calendar_id set.
2. It **MUST NOT** have any "events" that occur during the time range.  (no overlap, the event must not converge with the datetime range in any way).
3. I would like to skip all the buildings that don't have any floors.

SQLFiddle with data here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/a6370

Comment: Sample data and http://sqlfiddle.com would be nice

Comment: @lad2025 working on sqlfiddle - should have something up in a minute or two.

Comment: @lad2025 done.  Data is in the fiddle

Comment: There's a typo "calednar" in one of the columns. I left the typo in my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got this.

```
select organization_building.id as "id",
       organization_building.name as "building_name", 
       COUNT(organization_floor.id) AS "Floor Available", 
       tmp.f AS "Floors_Total" 
FROM organization_floor INNER JOIN organization_building 
                  ON organization_floor.building_id = organization_building.id 
     INNER JOIN (select building_id, COUNT(*) AS "f" from organization_floor GROUP BY building_id) AS tmp 
                  ON organization_building.id=tmp.building_id
WHERE calendar_id in (select calendar_id from organization_event 
                                         where "start" >='2015-11-03' OR "end" < '2015-11-04') 
      and tmp.f > 0 GROUP BY organization_building.id, tmp.f;
```

It is not the best way to resolve the task, but i tried :)

Comment: i'll fix it if i find better query

Comment: It works!  Yours and shawn's are giving different results, so I'll have to study them both.

Answer (score 1):

A guess (not sure if I understand the data/requirements):

```
select
    of.building_id as Building_Id,
    (
        select name from organization_building ob
        where ob.id = of.building_id
    ) as Building_Name,
    count(distinct of.id) as Floors_Total,
    count(distinct of.id) -
        count(distinct
            case when oe.end < ?start? and oe.start > ?end?
            then of.id else null end
        ) as Floors_Available
from
    organization_floor of
    left outer join
    organization_event oe
        on oe.calendar_id = of.calendar_id
group by
    of.building_id
```

I don't know Postgres specific SQL. And then the fiddle was breaking so I couldn't even do a smoke test on it.

I put the name column in a subquery to isolate it from the rest of the logic which is really the heart of you question. You might prefer to incorporate it back into the query later.

Comment: Yeah, it won't run for me on sqlfiddle either, and neither will @ruslan-galimov 's, but I tried it in the postgres terminal and got this: `ERROR:  column oe.calednar_id does not exist
LINE 17: on oe.calednar_id = of.calendar_id
            ^`

Comment: I mentioned that in a comment above. You had a typo in the fiddle you created so I just left it that way.

Comment: Ah, I fixed that, but not before you posted yours.  It works now!  Unfortunately the two answers give different results, so I'll have to study and figure out which one is correct.

Comment: Yeah, looks like yours is the correct one.  Thanks!